# Taylor Remainder, $\arcsin(x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

Given that the $0$ degree Taylor polynomial centered at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ for $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$ is given by $T_{0,\frac{1}{2}}(x)=\frac{\pi}{6}$ how would I use this to show that $1.2(x-\frac{1}{2})\leq R_{0,\frac{1}{2}}(x) \leq(x-\frac{1}{2})$ on $[0.4,0.5]$

I know that by Taylor's theorem $R_{0,\frac{1}{2}}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}(x-\frac{1}{2}$) and since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is an increasing function on $[0.4,0.5]$ that $R_{0,\frac{1}{2}}(x) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.5^2}}(x-\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: The function you mention is not increasing, it is decreasing.

Comment: @daulomb ??? It is increasing.

Comment: Yes you are right I supposed just square root thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since as you notice
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.4^2}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.5^2}},
$$
all you need to prove is that 
$$
\color{red}{1\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.4^2}}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\le\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.5^2}}\le 1.2}
$$
and then multiply by $x-0.5$, which is *negative* for $0.4\le x\le 0.5$, so the inequalities become reversed.

Comment: why the negative? when the bounds are with a positive (x-0.5)

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt I mean, for $0.4\le x\le 0.5$ the quantity $x-0.5$ is *negative*. For example. $0.4-0.5=-0.1$.